How can I fill a specific cell depending on values in multiple other cells?
I have a extremely large Excel file with multiple columns. How can I, for example, put a formula in cell I2 to first check if A2 and B2 are a specific value, and then find the value of cell E2 based on the values of G2 and K2, and then paste the value of E2 into I2?
I'm not sure what to try whether it's a formula or a Macro.

If the resulting cell is not part of the calculations, you could use a formula. Please share more information. Describe in detail the whole process for a single line using actual values and formulas. Also, use a table markdown generator to add sample data of the before and after.

Can you clarify this: find the value of cell E2 based on the values of G2 and K2, and then paste the value of E2 into I2 Maybe some example of source data and expected result?

What does the size of the file have to do with the question if you're only using 5 cells in your formula? Or did you mean something else possibly? Without sample data, example(s) it's hard to tell.

To create a solution based on Excel formulas, let's analyze the statement:

"then paste the value of E2 into I2"

I2 =E2


"check if A2 and B2 are a specific value" is the condition. "find the value of cell E2 based on the values of G2 and K2" is the action to perform if the condition is true.

E2 =IF(AND(A2=Value1,B2=Value2),FunctionGKtoE(G2,K2),"")

where "FunctionGKtoE" is the function to get the value based on the values of G2 and K2. It can be directly defined in place or as the named formula.

This answer leaves just as much to ask as the question itself.

@P.b It answers as much as possible. If TS needs help to compose the FunctionGKtoE function, it shall ask with details.

I think the question needs improvement prior to answering.

@P.b Sure! Sometimes you need to take a situation to the point of absurdity for a person to understand what he is doing wrong. :-)
